# state variable response of non-homogenuous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

The following one-dimensional ODE is considered:

$\dot x(t) = -a \, x(t) + u(t),\quad x(0)=x_0,$

with $a>0$.

The solution is given as

$x(t) = x_0\exp(-a\,t) + \exp(-a\,t)\int_0^\tau\exp(a\,\tau)u(\tau)\,d\tau$.

I want analyse the behavior of $x$ for $a\to\infty$. Intuitively it is clear that for large $a$ and if $u(t)$ does not vary too fast, the solution $x(t) \approx \frac{1}{a}u(t)$. The larger $a$ is, the better $x\,a$ approaches $u(t)$. In simulation this can be easily verified.

Can soemone give me a hint how to analyse this observation mathematically? More clearly how to relate the solution $x(t)$ with $a$ and the variation of $u(t)$?

I tried to consider fast and slow time-scales, however, so far I stucked in the deviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the explicit form of the solution

$$
x(t) = x_0 e^{-at} + e^{-at} \int_0^t e^{a\tau} u(\tau)\,d\tau
$$

make the substitution $\tau = t - s$ to get

$$
x(t) = x_0 e^{-at} + \int_0^t e^{-as}u(t-s)\,ds
$$

then apply [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) to approximate the integral.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable hint! If I see it right, Watson's Lemma states the asymptotic approximation of the exponential integral. However, there the time dependence might get lost. I mean that I don't see how can it be useful if u(t) is actually not given analytically. (Well I haven't read a lot yet about asymptotic analysis, though it's interesting: Maybe I understand more later on) Do you think Watson's Lemma is more appropriate if u(t) is given anaytically?

Comment: @Carlos, Sorry, I don't understand your question. Watson's lemma says that, for fixed $t$, $$\int_0^t e^{-as} u(t-s)\,ds \sim \frac{u(t)}{a}$$ as $a \to +\infty$, assuming that $u(t)$ exists and that $u(t-s)$ is integrable for $0 \leq s \leq t$ and is continuous in $s$ for small $s \geq 0$.

Comment: This result was actually that i was looking for in the result of Watson's Lemma, i.e. the asymptotic equivalence $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)(0)}\Gamma(a+n+1)}{n!t^{a+n+1}}$. However I don't understand how to interpret the Gamma function correctly or how to come to the conclusion that here the results ~$\frac{u(t)}{a}$ really holds.

Comment: @Carlos, You seem to have renamed some variables in the series from Watson's lemma -- perhaps that's causing some confusion. Try this instead: Watson's lemma says that $$\int_0^T e^{-as} \phi(s)\,ds \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(n)}(0) \Gamma(\lambda+n+1)}{n! a^{\lambda+n+1}},$$ where $\phi(s) = s^\lambda g(s)$. For your problem $\phi(s) = u(t-s)$ and so $\lambda = 0$ and $g(s) = u(t-s)$. Thus $g(0) = u(t-0) = u(t)$. Therefore the first term in the series is $$\frac{g^{(0)}(0) \Gamma(0 + 0 + 1)}{0! a^{0+0+1}} = \frac{u(t)}{a}.$$

Comment: This makes it fairly clear! Thank you!

Comment: @ Antonio, the form of Watson's lemma in your [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3695) i find really interesting. Do you have further references where i can find more information about that? Actually i try to understand the difference of the forms: It seems that  in $\Phi(\lambda) = \int_0^T t^{\sigma}h(t)e^{-\lambda t} dt = \frac{h(0)\Gamma(\sigma +1)}{\lambda^{\sigma+1}} + O(\lambda^{-\sigma-2})$ it is just the first partial sum for $n = 0$. I try to understand the difference between the "usual" form as above with the infinite series.

Comment: @Carlos, the main idea is that when you have the proper conditions to obtain the full infinite series, each successive term in the series gives you a better and better approximation to the integral (as the variable becomes large). There are many situations (i.e. weak restrictions on the function $\phi(s)$) where the integral can be proved to be asymptotic to the first term of the series ($n=0$), slightly fewer situations where you get the first **two** terms of the series ($n=0$ and $n=1$), and many fewer situations where you can prove that the integral has the full series expansion.

Comment: @Carlos, A good reference for that version of Watson's lemma is Miller's Applied Asymptotic Analysis. I also wrote a detailed appendix to my thesis (which can be downloaded [here](https://dalspace.library.dal.ca/handle/10222/72055)) on Watson's lemma and related results.

Comment: @ Antonio, i think now i take it. Thanks, perfect!